# Rails Active Record Query: Join on Child Condition to include only matching results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models - **Publisher** and **Policy**.  Policies belong to Publishers, and Publishers have many policies.  Within the Policy model, there is a column called "**ad_partner**", and I'm looking to find Publishers who do not have a policy containing a specific value within the ad partner. The end goal being a list of publishers who not have any policies associated with a specific ad_partner.

This is my current query:

```
test = Publisher.joins(:policies).select('publishers.name, 
publishers.id, publishers.domain').where.not("policies.ad_partner ILIKE 
?", 'indexexchange.com').group("publishers.id, 
publishers.name").limit(10)
```

And the output looks like this:

```
 +----+------------------+---------------------+
| id | name             | domain              |
 +----+------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | Business Insider | businessinsider.com |
| 2  | Wired            | wired.com           |
| 3  | CNET             | cnet.com            |
| 4  | Weather Channel  | weather.com         |
| 5  | Time Inc         | time.com            |
| 6  | IGN              | ign.com             |
| 7  | CBS              | cbs.com             |
| 8  | NBC              | nbc.com             |
| 9  | TMZ              | tmz.com             |
| 10 | HGTV             | hgtv.com            |
+----+------------------+---------------------+
```

This is incorrect, because I know most if not all of these publishers have policies that contain *indexexchange.com* as a value within ad_partner. What I suspect is happening is that the query is saying "ok we are removing the policies from the JOIN list, and outputting the remaining policies grouped by publisher, when in fact I want to FIND publishers who have this condition, not create the condition as it appears to be doing.  I have a feeling there is an obvious error here, but I've been struggling to find it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a model? Post it please. also your schema.rb please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

> publishers who [do] not have any policies associated with a specific ad_partner

so say exactly that. First find the publishers that *do* have such a policy:

```
Policy.where('ad_partner ilike ?', partner).select(:publisher_id)
```

and then find the publishers that aren't in that list:

```
Publisher.where.not(
  id: Policy.select(:publisher_id).where('ad_partner ilike ?', partner)
)
```

Including the `select(:publisher_id)` in the `Policy` query will tell ActiveRecord to use a subquery so the result will be SQL like this:

```
select *
from publisher
where id not in (
  select publisher_id
  from policies
  where ad_partner ilike 'indexexchange.com'
)
```

That will give you the publishers you're after without duplicates. Then you can add whatever ordering and limits you need.

Your original query doesn't work the way you want it to because the JOIN will produce rows that contain everything:

```
publisher1_columns, policy_with_partner
publisher1_columns, policy_without_partner
publisher1_columns, policy_without_partner
publisher2_columns, policy_without_partner
...
```

and then your WHERE will only exclude the first row in the JOIN leaving the two "publisher1" rows you don't want.

---

Saying `ilike 'indexexchange.com'` is just a complicated way of doing a case-insensitive equality. If you want pattern matching then you'd say:

```
where('ad_partner ilike ?', "%#{partner}%")
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the clarification - you're right I wasn't asking "the right question" in the query.   This works: 
    `Publisher.where.not(
      id: Policy.select(:publisher_id).where('ad_partner ilike ?', partner)
    )`

However it includes publishers who may not have **any** policies, which is less than useful.  What if I want to run the same query, but only wanted the list to include publishers **who have** policies, but just not a specific ad_partner

Comment: I think I answered my own question - I broke it into two queries

`active = Publisher.joins(:policies).group('publishers.id')` 

to select the active publishers, and then ran your query: 

`missing2 = active.select(:id, :name, :domain, :articles_count).where.not( id: Policy.select(:publisher_id).where('ad_partner ilike ?', 'indexexchange.com')).order(:id)`